# Angry birds on google chrome doesn't have any sound?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Downloaded angry birds from the chrome web store onto my chromium web browser. But when I start the game it doesn't have any audio. Is this some known issue with the browser on ubuntu? I run ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in Chromium:

http://chrome.angrybirds.com/?gwt-voices=flash

It worked with me.

Comment: Please don't just link. Include the relevant information from the link. If the site ever goes down, your answer is useless. Read [answer].

Comment: Worked for me, tks.

Comment: @user99572isfine The answer is not information at that link, the link _is_ the answer!

Comment: @reuben Now, why is that not written in the answer? The link does not answer the question. Answering implies that one should explain what the link does and how clicking on it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although Angry Birds for Chrome claims to be all HTML5 the sound is played through Adobe Flash. Without a proper version of Flash enabled you won't get any sound.